# Export gridview to excel WITHOUT gridview formatting

Tags: c#, gridview, export-to-excel

I have tried many things to just to export data only from the gridview. But it always export gridview formatting as well. Below is my code

```
private void ExportGridToExcel()
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Charset = "";

        string fileName = "QAFormNotReceived" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xls";
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);

        gvInsQANotReceived.HeaderStyle.Reset();
        gvInsQANotReceived.FooterStyle.Reset();
        gvInsQANotReceived.AlternatingRowStyle.Reset();
        gvInsQANotReceived.RowStyle.Reset();

        gvInsQANotReceived.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        gvInsQANotReceived.GridLines = GridLines.None;
        gvInsQANotReceived.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
        Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

This the Excel spreadsheet

[image: current spreadsheet]

Spreadsheet I require 
[image: Spreadsheet I require]

Any help is appreciated. I know next option is to try to use a string builder and write the rows one by one.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like Font is different.

Comment: @jdweng first image has some formatting. I just want the data as shown in the second image